# Sufficient conditions for exact signal recovery using OMP?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, signal-detection, compressive-sensing, sparsity

For a compressive sensing model : 
$$y_{_{MXN}}=A_{_{MXN}}x_{_{NX1}}$$
where $x$ is $K$ sparse, what is the sufficient condition for Orthogonal matching Pursuit (OMP) to exactly recover the data for both noisy and noiseless case ?

There are multiple statements, like

- $M>Klog(N-K)$ ;
- $M>Klog(N/K)$ ;
- $M>2Klog(N-K)$ ;
- somewhere it's $M>4Klog(N-K)$.

Should there be some constant ratio between $M$ and $N$?